# How to match expected input shape to array shape in CNN model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am attempting a CNN for classification of biological data (EEG data). However, after importing and splitting the data into train/test/dev sets and building the CNN, I cannot get the input array shape to match the expected array shape.

Note: Data contains 5 trials/samples for each participant(ID's) in the study, so GSS was used to ensure data from each participant was not mixed train and test sets.

Code and error as follows:

```
 #Load Data
def load_all_data(filename):
    import numpy as np

    a = np.load(filename)
    d = (dict(zip(("data1{}".format(k) for k in a), (a[k] for k in a))))

    return d

filename = ("dataname.npz") 
X = load_all_data(filename)['array_0']
y = load_all_data(filename)['array_1']

IDs = load_all_data(filename)['array_2']   

#Split Test Data with Groupshuffle Split
from  sklearn.model_selection import GroupShuffleSplit
import numpy as np
test_size = 0.2
gss = GroupShuffleSplit(n_splits = 1, test_size = 0.2)

for train,test in gss.split(X, y, IDs):
    X_train = X[train]
    y_train = y[train]
    IDs_train = IDs[train]

    X_test = X[test]
    y_test = y[test]
    IDs_test = IDs[test]

fileoutname = 'train_test_data'
np.savez(fileoutname,X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test,IDs_train,IDs_test)

#Split Train, Test Data
gss = GroupShuffleSplit(1, test_size)

for train,test in gss.split(X, y, IDs):
    X_train2 = X[train]
    y_train2 = y[train]
    IDs_train = IDs[train]

    X_dev = X[test]
    y_dev = y[test]
    IDs_test = IDs[test]

#Add dimension to X and Convert y to Categorical
X_train2 = np.expand_dims(X_train2,axis=0)
y_train2 = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train2,num_classes=2)
X_dev = np.expand_dims(X_test,axis=0)
y_dev = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test,num_classes=2)
X = np.expand_dims(X,axis=0)

#Build the CNN
def  simpleCNN(self, units = 10):

    import keras
    from keras.layers import Dense
    from keras.layers import Conv2D
    from keras.layers import Flatten
    from keras.models import Model, Input

    inp =  Input(shape = self.shape[1:], name='inp')
   #layer 1
    x = Conv2D(units, kernel_size=(1,1), strides = (1,1), activation='relu', data_format='channels_last')(inp)  
    #layer 2
    x = Conv2D(units, kernel_size=(2,2), strides = (1,1), activation='relu', data_format='channels_last')(x)  
    #layer 3 
    x = Flatten()(x)
   #layer4
    out = Dense(2, activation='softmax',name='out')(x)

    model = Model(inputs = inp, outputs = out)

    return model

#Fit the Data
model = simpleCNN(X)
from keras.optimizers import Adamax
adamax = Adamax(lr=3e-4, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0); #3e-4; 2e-3 is a default.
model.compile(optimizer=adamax, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
model.fit(X_train2, y_train2, epochs=20, batch_size=32, verbose = 1, validation_data = (X_dev, y_dev))


ValueError: Error when checking input: expected inp to have shape (11459, 26, 60) but got array with shape (9065, 26, 60)
```

Comment: Looks like Your model is expecting 11459 that is the size of X(above #layer 1)
And you are passing X_train2 which has 9065.
And I also suspect that the way you are constructing data is wrong.
We usually have input_shape to be (n,m,3) 60 in the third dimension looks wrong to me.

Comment: But what is causing X_train2 to show 9065? It is actually changing the value of the  first number in the array each time I re-run the code, but only the first value. I suspect it is as a result of the GroupShuffleSplit? Is that correct?